# Getting error on uploading code into esp8266 nodemcu by Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

Recently I bought a esp8266 nodemcu for my project.
For running the blink code, I followed this tutorial [esp8266 quick start.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Quick-Start-to-Nodemcu-ESP8266-on-Arduino-IDE/)

But ended up with this :

> Sketch uses 246,319 bytes (23%) of program storage space.Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes.
>
> Global variables use 32,276 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,644 bytes for local variables.Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
>
> Uploading 250464 bytes from C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Temp\build544514107263874658.tmp/arduinowifi.cpp.bin to flash at 0x00000000
>
> .error: failed sending 1044 bytes
>
> error: failed sending 0xC0
>
> warning: espcomm_send_command: didn't receive command response
>
> warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_DATA) failed
>
> error: failed sending 0xC0
>
> error: failed sending 8 bytes
>
> error: failed sending 4 bytes
>
> error: failed sending 0xC0
>
> warning: espcomm_send_command: didn't receive command response
>
> error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

I tried with different baud rate but failed.

Arduino IDE: 1.6.5 and 1.8.5

OS: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Update: Solved after using USB HUB.

Comment: Do you mean Ubuntu 16.04LTS?  There's no such thing as Linux 16.04

Comment: @Delta_G My bad! I mean Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Answer (score 2):

The problem may come from circuit breakdown. I have this problem today and solved by following.  Jump D3 (or GPIO00) to GND (if your PC still can see port). However, GPIO0 is set to OUTPUT/HIGH by default and may cause excessive current consumption.  To prevent board fail, 1K resister may add between GPIO0(D3) and GND.  Plug module power and upload program.  Sometimes, please remember that you may need to unplug and plug module every new upload.
For another method,direct program to chip, use FTD232 (switch jumper to 3.3V) connect between FTD232 and NodeMCU like as Vcc(check it is 3.3V):3.3V , Tx:Rx, Rx:Tx, Gnd:Gnd, Gnd:D3. (you may use on board GND to D3)
Plug and upload.  if the second method cannot work your ESP8266 IC may be gone.
As mention above, if your ESP8266 set GPIO0 as OUTPUT/HIGH, ground it may damage chip.  Make sure that you 
1) unplug power before ground GPIO0 (or add a resister)
2) power it and upload
3) remove GPIO0 when enter upload to prevent short out the output when program start to run.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to install the driver for the nodeMCU! You can get it here:
https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

And then go to control panel->devices and check if your system detects the nodeMCU.

Next go to preferences and add the board to Arduino IDE

Next disconnect and reconnect (just for confirmation) to verify if a led(blue usually) blinks upon connection.

After these steps, then go to Arduino IDE and select the board as ESP -12E module
Set the programmer as AVRiSP mk ll
And then compile and upload!

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I did everything you mentioned. :-) But hard luck.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers ✌️

Comment: Are you pressing the reset and flash buttons when you start the upload?

Comment: Did you check the control panel? And did the nodeMCU flicker upon connection? If it didn't, then it means your NodeMCU is not working!

Comment: The NODEMCU flicker upon connection. I think the NodeMCU is ok.But I will with another nodeMCU,data cable and PC.

Comment: And what about control panel? Did it show the device is connected on a port?

Comment: Yes. I was connected with COM5(in windows)  and it showed "Silicon labs cp210x usb to urat bridge"

Comment: Worked fine after using USB HUB. Most probably due to lack of enough current,could not upload the code.Thanks!

Comment: Cheers buddy ✌️!